Javascript Jose Sign And Encrypt JWT
I am using jose to sign and encrypt JWTs. However I am unable to sign and then encrypt my whole JWT.
I use this function to sign my jwt:
const secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const key = new TextEncoder().encode(secretKey);

export async function _encrypt(payload: any) {
  return await new SignJWT(payload)
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
    .setIssuedAt()
    .setExpirationTime("10 sec from now")
    .sign(key);
}

I am using following code to encrypt it (when passing an JWT object it works):
const now = () => (Date.now() / 1000) | 0;

const alg = "dir";
const enc = "A256CBC-HS512";

...

sync function encrypt({
  payload,
  maxAge,
}: {
  payload: JWTPayload;
  maxAge: number;
}): Promise<string> {
  const secret: Uint8Array = randomBytes(32);
  const salt = randomBytes(16);
  const encryptionSecret: Uint8Array = await hkdf(
    "sha256",
    secret,
    salt,
    "Generated Encryption Key",
    32
  );
  
  return new EncryptJWT(payload)
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg, enc })
    .setIssuedAt()
    .setExpirationTime(now() + maxAge)
    .setJti(crypto.randomUUID())
    .encrypt(encryptionSecret);
}

The code does not work as intended because EncryptJWT does only accept an JWT object. This is also reflected in the console: error TypeError: JWT Claims Set MUST be an object

To sign then encrypt you want to use the SignJWT class to sign and then CompactEncrypt to encrypt the signed result. An example of this is in https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/112. just replace the key management with your secrets and use appropriate algorithms.

Thank you so much. Can you post your comment as an answer?

To sign then encrypt you want to use the SignJWT class to sign and then CompactEncrypt to encrypt the signed result. An example of this is in https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/112, just replace the key management with your secrets and use appropriate algorithms.
